# What's the difference between the Daredevil and Hot Rod hoverboards?

Tags: subway-surfers

Some boards in the shop have special powers associated with them. I'm interested in investing a significant amount of coins in one of these boards, but would like to know what their differences are before making that commitment.

The Daredevil board's special power is "Surf Faster". The Hot Rod's special power is "Speed Up". What's the difference between these two special powers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update sometime in the past renamed all powerups to "Speed up". So, the functionality between these two boards are effectively the same.

Answer (score 3):

I'll tell you the difference. It is that the Hot Rod sucks!

In all seriousness though, it is slower than Daredevil and does not maintain speed after usage which might make it worth it. Buy Daredevil.